# On the derivative of $\phi(u) = {}^tu'u'$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

I am reading *Pseudo-differential Operators and the Nash-Moser Theorem* by Gerard and Alinhac. I am confused with one of the results stated (but not proven) in the book.

On page 133, given $u : M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $M$ is a $C^\infty$ compact Riemannian manifold), the book defines (for a quadratic form $g = \sum g_{ij}(x) \mathrm{d}x_i \mathrm{d}x_j$):
$$
g_{ij} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}
$$
and abbreviates $g = {}^tu'u'$ (alternatively, I believe one may view $g$ as an $n \times n$ matrix). On page 140, the book then defines:
$$
\phi(u) = {}^tu'u' 
$$
I have two questions here.

1. Below the definition, the book writes $\phi'(u)v = {}^tu'v' + {}^tv'u'$, where . I'm not sure how they obtained this result. I presume they are computing the derivative of $\phi(u)$ then apply it to the vector $v$. One may refer to page 135 for the precise definition of $\phi'$.
2. I would like to compute the second derivative $\phi''(u)(v,w)$, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be rather simple calculations, with the fact I didn't realise the workings is because I didn't realise the author stated a different definition of the derivative (on page 135), which is:
\begin{align*}
    \Phi^{(k)}(u) \cdot (v_1,\dots,v_k) = \left.\frac{\partial^k}{\partial t_1 \cdots \partial t_k}\Phi(u + t_1v_1 + \cdots + t_kv_k)\right|_{t_1 = \cdots = t_k = 0}
\end{align*}
Then:
\begin{align*}
    \phi'(u)v &= \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi(u + tv)\right|_{t=0} \\
    &= \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}({}^t(u + tv)'(u + tv)')\right|_{t=0} \\
    &= \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}({}^tu'u' + t({}^tu'v' + {}^tv'u') + t^2({}^tv'v'))\right|_{t=0} \\
    &= {}^tu'v' + {}^tv'u'
\end{align*}
and for the second derivative:
\begin{align*}
    \phi''(u)(v,w) &= \left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1\partial t_2}\phi(u + t_1v + t_2w)\right|_{t_1 = t_2 = 0} \\
    &= \left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1\partial t_2}{}^t(u + t_1v + t_2w)'(u + t_1v + t_2w)'\right|_{t_1 = t_2 = 0} \\
    &= \left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1\partial t_2}{}^t(u' + t_1v' + t_2w')(u' + t_1v' + t_2w')\right|_{t_1 = t_2 = 0} \\
    &= {}^tv'w' + {}^tw'v'
\end{align*}